# How to do background process in free PHP heroku

Tags: php, heroku, timeout, background-process

I need to do background process in PHP Heroku because Heroku has 30 second limitation for the request. Request will terminate if it takes longer than 30 seconds to complete. I had used Syfony 2.0 but Symfony automatically stops child process(Background Process) when its main thread completes So it doesn't works for me. I am using PHP Heroku Free Hosting.  Please explain me that How to do background process in PHP free Heroku Hosting. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)